# Github Actions - Same workflow name, different branches. Which takes priority?

Tags: github, github-actions

If I have a workflow in two branches "dev" and "main" with the same name and content, which one takes precedence? Or will both workflows run? What happens if the content of the two workflows is different, but the workflow name is the same?

Assume I have this workflow below on the main branch, but I have a slightly different version on a "dev" branch with the same file name and trigger (both on push branches dev). Would both execute on a push to "dev"?

```yaml
name: .NET Core CI

on:   
  push:
    branches:
      - dev

env:
  AZURE_WEBAPP_NAME: ghactiontest    # set this to your application's name
  AZURE_WEBAPP_PACKAGE_PATH: '.'      # set this to the path to your web app project, defaults to the repository root
  DOTNET_VERSION: '6.0'           # set this to the dot net version to use

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      # Checkout the repo
      - uses: actions/checkout@main
      
      # Setup .NET Core SDK
      - name: Setup .NET Core
        uses: actions/setup-dotnet@v1
        with:
          dotnet-version: ${{ env.DOTNET_VERSION }} 
      
      # Run dotnet build and publish
      - name: dotnet build and publish
        run: |
          dotnet restore
          dotnet build --configuration Release
          dotnet publish -c Release -o '${{ env.AZURE_WEBAPP_PACKAGE_PATH }}/myapp' 
          
      # Deploy to Azure Web apps
      - name: 'Run Azure webapp deploy action using publish profile credentials'
        uses: azure/webapps-deploy@v2
        with: 
          app-name: ${{ env.AZURE_WEBAPP_NAME }} # Replace with your app name
          publish-profile: ${{ secrets.AZURE_WEBAPP_PUBLISH_PROFILE  }} # Define secret variable in repository settings as per action documentation
          package: '${{ env.AZURE_WEBAPP_PACKAGE_PATH }}/myapp'
```

Comment: Edit your question and show the workflow(s).

Comment: It can depend on the workflow trigger. But if it's not a (global) push trigger, the `default` branch workflow will be prioritize (in your case, the main branch). Note that if you use a wokflow_dispatch trigger, you can choose the branch to execute the workflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested this with a simple hello world workflow on the "main" and "dev" branches. If there is an "on push" trigger for a given branch, the workflow must exist on that branch. A workflow on "main" with a trigger for both "main" and "dev" will only execute on a push to "main" if there's no corresponding workflow on "dev".

```yaml
name: .NET Core CI Cert

on:   
  push:
    branches:
      - cert
      - main
jobs:
  my-job:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: my-step
        run: echo "Hello World Cert Branch!"
```

Answer (score 0):

Normally this workflow will run for both `dev` and `main` - can you post your exact workflow?

Two workflows with the same name will also run separately and will be considered two different workflows with two different `workflow_id`s - but they will appear using the same name.

Answer (score 0):

Since all workflows are suppose to be located in `.github/workflows` directory and they cannot be inside sub directories theoretically you cannot create more than one workflow with same name in this directory.
To answer your other question, if you want to run a workflow for a specific branch you can use the branch syntax as following:

```
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
```

Just create your workflows with different names and let them get triggered when push or pull request event is triggered for respective branch.

Comment: You can create two files with the same name in two different branches - I think that you will get assigned two different ids in this case

Comment: @mmomtchev can you point me this theory in the official docs?

Comment: Just a personal observation, I use the API and I see the ids